# Set the Angular CLI build location

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 project generated with the Angular CLI (by typing `ng new myProject`).

How can I configure the build location, so after the build I will have a separate folder with all HTML, JS and other resources?

Comment: So, you would want another directory than the default dist directory? Why not copy the contents of dist where you want it after the build instead?

Comment: The CLI already does this, that's what `ng build` is for. If you want to change the output directory, look in `angular-cli.json`.

Comment: Yes, the solution was to edit outDir in angular-cli.json file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 Steps:

1. Edit outDir in **angular-cli.json** file.

[image]

(In this case the build will be located in "static" folder one step above project root directory)

2. Type **ng build** in the project root directory.

Comment: In Angular 6 onwards this configuration file is `angular.json` and it is `outputPath` rather than `outDir`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Tomas Marik is correct for cases where you always want to use that output folder. But for cases where you need to be more flexible, you can also override the `.angular-cli.json` value by specifying it on the command line. This works for both `ng build` and `ng serve`:

```
ng build --output-path ../path/to/use
```